# Pesquisar se há ou não registro na array()

Tags: php

```
$detalhes->pro_are_id = '["4","1","2","3","6"]'; // Dados foram gravados no banco atraés do json_encode()
$valor->are_id = 2;

if(!empty($detalhes) and isset($detalhes->pro_are_id)){ 
    $are_id = json_decode($detalhes->pro_are_id);
    if(array_search($valor->are_id, $are_id)){
        $existe = 1;
    }
}
```

O problema é que dentro do loop com todos os objetos selecionados ou 1 ou 2, ele exibe sempre faltando um.
Exemplo, se eu pesquisar pelo id 2,3,6 ele só vem o 3 e 4. O 2 já não exibe.
**é sempre o primeiro id que não compara.**

Como ajustar isto?

No conjunto geral é este:

```
<p class="mb20">Selecione uma ou mais áreas</p>                         
<select id="select-multi" name="pro_are_id[]" data-placeholder="Escolha 1 ou +" multiple="" class="width300 select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1">
    <option>Selecione</option>
    <?php 
        $existe = 0;
        foreach($listagem_area as $valor){
            if(!empty($detalhes) and isset($detalhes->pro_are_id)){ 
                $are_id = json_decode($detalhes->pro_are_id);
                if(array_search($valor->are_id, $are_id)){
                    $existe = 1;
                }
            }                                               

    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $valor->are_id; ?>" <?php if($existe==1) echo "selected"; ?> ><?php echo $valor->are_titulo; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: O que é `$listagem_area`?

Comment: O `array_search` retorna a chave da array encontrada, se ela for `0` o `if` entenderá como `false` (devido a fraca tipagem do PHP). Logo você deveria utilizar `array_search($valor->are_id, $are_id) !== false`, isto é um dos erros. Na verdade poderia utilizar o `in_array()` ou poderia utilizar o `array_intersect()` para obter os valores comuns em ambas as arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso provavelmente ocorre devido a tipagem fraca do PHP, o `array_search` retorna a chave da array que possui o valor indicado.

Portanto considere isto:

```
var_export( array_search(1, [1,2,3]) );
// 0
```

Isto é equivalente a fazer:

```
if(0){
   echo 'Nunca será exibido :('; 
}
```

Isso é o que ocorre porque a `array_search(1, [1,2,3])` é `0` que será "convertido" para um boolean como `false`, nunca será mostrado a mensagem.

Portanto altere para:

```
if(array_search(1, [1,2,3]) !== false){
   $existe = 1;
}
```

Neste caso o `0` é diferente de `false` (utilizando o  `===`). Nesta condição ele existe. Se não existir o `array_search` retorna `false` e neste caso `false === false` logo não existe.

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3836fe7d7aed69d5d552e28e22a91e6122dd7c2)

Comment: Perfeitamente @Inkeliz obrigado, era isso. E entendi também sua explicação, simples e objetiva. Grato!